# Get multiple time restarted pod list in kubernate

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl, minikube

From the below pods, how can we get a list of pods which have been restarted more than 2 times. How can we get in a single line query ?

```
xx-5f6df977d7-4gtxj                 3/3     Running            0          6d21h
xx-5f6df977d7-4rvtg                 3/3     Running            0          6d21h
pkz-ms-profile-df9fdc4f-2nqvw       1/1     Running            0          76d
push-green-95455c5c-fmkr7           3/3     Running            3          15d
spice-blue-77b7869847-6md6w         2/2     Running            0          19d
bang-blue-55845b9c68-ht5s5             1/3     Running            2          8m50s
mum-blue-6f544cd567-m6lws                  2/2     Running            3          76d
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually is not possible to use field selector to get this result, as mentioned in this github open [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/49387).

You can use `kubectl` with the option `-o jsonpath` to get the container name that whas restart more than 2 times. Example:

```sh
kubectl get pods -o jsonpath='{.items[*].status.containerStatuses[?(@.restartCount>=2)].name}'
```

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
kubectl get pods | awk '{if($4>2)print$1}'
```

Use `-n "NameSpace"` if required to fetch pods on the basis of a namespace.
For example:

`kubectl get pods -n kube-system | awk '{if($4>2)print$1}'`

where $1, $4 : Depends on which column pod name is present , column on which filter is to be done respectively

**Note**: `awk` will work in linux whereas

Comment: Is it possible to use field selector to get this result.

Comment: It is not possible with field selector. @xyz_scala